# How to provide input to questions on hold as a low rep user

Tags: discussion

This question: ["What makes a computer a computer? [closed]"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307369/what-makes-a-computer-a-computer) has been put on hold.

The original poster was unable to ask their question in a format suitable for this medium but I think the implied question - What is the difference between ASICs/micro-controllers and computers? - can be addressed to add value.

While more specific, this question: ["Is BeagleBone Black a microcontroller or computer?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/182322/is-beaglebone-black-a-microcontroller-or-computer) is along the same lines but I feel fails to address some of the theoretical components.

I have written an answer - referencing Alan Turing's model for computation and the critical differences between memory management between micro-controllers and computers that I think could elucidate the subject (i.e. without an MMU microcontrollers lack support for crucial paradigms like processes, dynamic linking, and protected memory that most programmers use to reason about computers).

I would normally include this in a comment but as a low rep user I am unable to do so, nor am I able to direct message the poster.

Do I have any recourse?

Comment: You could post your answer to that 2015 question.  It's open.

Comment: No, the question was not about the *difference* between the types - the poster explained that in the question itself. Rather it ws about which qualifies as a computer.  And that hinges entirely on the definition of the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully not.

The point of closing a question is to prevent bad questions getting the desired result.  Unfortunately, there are always some who either don't care about the site quality or put their own personal looking smart ahead of it.  As a result, we have to lock them out.

Those very new here are much more likely to not get how this site works, and blunder around making a mess or otherwise defeating the quality mechanisms.  We therefore try to limit what newcomers can do before they become more in tune with the site mechanics.

Rep is used as the measure of how much we trust you to deal responsibly with these issues.  It's not perfect, but reasonable enough.  To put it bluntly, you only have 18 rep, so we don't want you doing these things because we don't trust you to do them right.

The solution is not to look for ways around this system, but to learn the site and its customs.  That comes with time and experience here, measured in rep.  There are quite a lot of privileges that you earn at various rep levels.  The system isn't perfect, but works well enough.  Whatever one thing you want to add to that question is immaterial in the larger scheme of things.  We'll be fine without it.

So go answer some questions or ask some good question yourself.  You'll get more rep and access to more privileges.  By that time, you'll hopefully understand how this site works, and what you do with those privileges will be beneficial to the site.

Comment: For those of us used to having some form of private correspondence on social publishing platforms, it does feel strange I can't reach out to the poster. Thanks for the information - The reason I asked isn't to subvert this system, but to explore it. (Poster has a twitter, I guess I'll DM him.)

Comment: @Steven: This is a question and answer site, not a Kaffee Klatsch or "forum".  That may not sound like much of a distinction to you now, which is why we don't want you messing with it.  It is in fact a major difference.  Hopefully by the time you've earned some privileges, you'll understand that difference.

Comment: I can appreciate and abide by the norms that create and curate a valuable set of information. A platform like this is both successful and limited by its users, and moderators, conforming to a rigid set of norms. I sent the poster an email, hopefully he finds it helpful and submits a better question next time.